# If accordion group ID is same - jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the accordion group name and run a condition if the group name is same, but condition is not working, what I am doing wrong here, can someone please check and suggest:

```
<div class="ab-Accordion ab-Accordion--block">
    <button id="test" type="button" class="Accordion-label js-Accordion" data-accordion-group="contact" role="tab" data-event-type="Accordion" data-event-details="Accordion" aria-selected="false">Accordion Title</button>
</div>

$(".ab-Accordion").bind('click',function(e){
    var accorgrpName = $(this).children().attr('data-accordion-group');
    //the above line return the group name in console correctly
    if ($(this).children().attr('data-accordion-group') == accorgrpName){
        console.log("this is same group - do something");
    }
});
```

This code is not working as expected in condition.

TIA

Comment: What does the relevant DOM look like and what output do you get in console? What are the values of `$(this).children().attr('data-accordion-group')` and `accorgrpName`? Are either of them `null` or `undefined`?

Comment: + Also show what is `this` in above statements?

Comment: Within a "click function" `this` can be not what you expect. Why don't you print the two values before comparing them, and understand why it is going wrong? Otherwise, just `bind` `this` to your "click function" to make sure you know what is `this`.

Comment: `$(this)` is not defined in any context here. Use some click function to let your code know what is `$(this)`

Comment: Without markup it is hard to predict what going on.

Comment: @AgiHammerthief I have updated the code

Comment: The problem is that you are comparing the same value in the if statement. `accorgrpName` is already set to be equal to `$(this).children().attr('data-accordion-group')`, and then you are comparing both values if they are equal

Comment: my requirement is to check if the value same as then fire an event, what approach do you suggest?

Comment: Can you give more code? Where the other accordion will be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store in a variable and that variable should be declared outside of function.

In the below example, we have 3 buttons with first 2 buttons having same group and last one having different group name.

Scenario 1:

- Click on first button
- Now click on second button (You should see
  'this is same group - do something')

Scenario 2:

- Click on first button
- Now click on third button (You should see
  'different group')

```js
var accorgrpName = '';
$(".ab-Accordion").bind('click', function(e) {
  if (accorgrpName != '') {
    //the above line return the group name in console correctly
    if ($(this).children().attr('data-accordion-group') == accorgrpName) {
      console.log("this is same group - do something");
    } else {
      console.log('different group');
    }
  } else {
    console.log('This is the first click.. now click some other button..')
  }
  accorgrpName = $(this).children().attr('data-accordion-group');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ab-Accordion ab-Accordion--block">
  <button id="test" type="button" class="Accordion-label js-Accordion" data-accordion-group="contact" role="tab" data-event-type="Accordion" data-event-details="Accordion" aria-selected="false">Accordion Title</button>
</div>
<div class="ab-Accordion ab-Accordion--block">
  <button id="test" type="button" class="Accordion-label js-Accordion" data-accordion-group="contact" role="tab" data-event-type="Accordion" data-event-details="Accordion" aria-selected="false">Accordion with same group</button>
</div>
<div class="ab-Accordion ab-Accordion--block">
  <button id="test" type="button" class="Accordion-label js-Accordion" data-accordion-group="contact-1" role="tab" data-event-type="Accordion" data-event-details="Accordion" aria-selected="false">Accordion with different group</button>
</div>
```